# Spring REST request mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, restful-url, spring-restcontroller, request-mapping

I want to configure Spring to redirect all the requests to a specific Controller irrespective of the URL (length and parameters). How should I give the URL pattern / regular expression in the RequestMapping annotation.  I tried using the below code, but it is not working. Any help in this regard is deeply appreciated.

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/*")
    public class ServiceController {
        @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "*" )
        public void getProjectList(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,Model model){

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/**")`.

From http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-patterns:

> In addition to URI templates, the `@RequestMapping` annotation also
>   supports **Ant-style path patterns** (for example, `/myPath/*.do`).

From http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html:

> The mapping matches URLs using the following rules:
>
> - `?` matches one character
> - `*` matches zero or more characters
> - **`**` matches zero or more *directories* in a path**

Comment: We have before used the above controller mapping without the method parameter, for a maintenance server to show that server is currently under maintenance. It works...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a regular expression?

Something like:

```
@RequestMapping("/{value:.}")
```

Comment: You want to change the request mapping on the top of class or on the top of the method. I tried in all possible ways, but it is not working.